# Is it possible to use NgZone inside of a singleton service?

Tags: angular, service, singleton

I'm trying to build an injectable singleton service for my app that would allow all provided components to know the window width and height and recognize when the page is scrolled or resized.

Here is the code for the service:

```ts
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ViewportService {
    public viewportHeight: number;
    public viewportWidth: number;
    public pageTop: number = 0;
    public mobile: boolean;

    constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {
        this.viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
        this.viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;

        if(this.viewportWidth < 1001) {
            this.mobile = true;
        }
        else {
            this.mobile = false;
        }

        window.onresize = (e) => {
            ngZone.run(() => {
                if(this.viewportWidth < 1001) {
                    this.mobile = true;
                } else {
                    this.mobile = false;
                }
            })
        }

        window.onscroll = (e) => {
            ngZone.run(() => {
                this.pageTop = window.scrollY;
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a component implementing it:

```ts
constructor(private viewportService: ViewportService) {
    this.mobile = viewportService.mobile;
    this.viewPortHeight = viewportService.viewportHeight;
    this.pageTop = viewportService.pageTop;

    if(this.mobile) {
        this.viewPortHeight = viewportService.viewportHeight - 70;
    }
    else {
        this.viewPortHeight = viewportService.viewportHeight - 270;
    }
}
```

The service is successfully injecting the data on page load but it does not update the component when the window events occur. Do I need to manually tell my component to watch the ViewportService for changes?

Comment: I noticed one glaring error in my service code where I don't even update the viewportHeight and viewportWidth variables in the run method, but that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is executed once for the component and copies the values from the service and then ignores the service.
These are primitive values and they are copied by value not by reference.

```ts
if(this.mobile) {
    this.viewPortHeight = viewportService.viewportHeight - 70;
}
else {
    this.viewPortHeight = viewportService.viewportHeight - 270;
}
```

Perhaps you want to use an Observable in the service where the component can subscribe to, to get notified about changes.
For examples see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

And yes. `NgZone` can be used in singleton services. There is only one zone for the whole Angular2 application.

Comment: I appreciate the prompt answer and I am going through the Angular2 docs to try and wrap my head around Observables, but I am starting to think that I have always been a moron.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot enter adds the comment. Another point for the moron theory! Anyway, how can I establish a Subject to be observed but also actually define its value? I cannot find this information anywhere and Angular2's docs just look like gibberish to me.

Comment: :D I'm not sure what you mean with your question. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service should demonstrate wat you need. You send new values with `.next(newValue)`

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you! The mistake I was making was assuming that I only would use the next() method for arrays.